# How to set TCP/IP settings in smart phone for a internet connection shared through a wifi by Windows 7 ad-hoc network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet, iphone, wifi-configuration

I have internet connection in my windows PC through a ethernet cable. Now i want to share internet connection with my phone over wifi. I created an ad-hoc network with internet connection sharing option

> Allow Other Network Users to Connect through This Computer’s Internet Connection

enabled by using adapter properties window in

> Manage Wireless Network

Now this ad-hoc network is internet access. After this step I conncted to that ad-hoc network from my iPhone. But Im getting a message in my phone that this ad-hoc network has no internet access. So I have to set the TCP/IP settings in my phone for that ad-hoc network. In my phone I have 3 options for setting IP address. They are

1. DHCP
2. BootP
3. Static

I dont know which 1 have to set. And I dont know about searching domain field Client IP field and Router field in the iPhone setting.

Some one explain how to connect this.

Comment: If you are going to set IP means you need select Static. If you select static only you can assign IP.

Comment: I'm not sure that I should assign the IP or automatically IP should be set. My ultimate aim is to share my pc internet with my phone. What should I do now?

Comment: Have you tried DHCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On your computer, open the Network and Sharing Center, click on your ad-hoc network then Details.
2. Write down the lines "IPv4 Address", "Subnet Mask" and "IPv4 DNS Server".
3. On your smmartphone, connect to the ad-hoc network. Set "Static IP".
4. The parameters are as follow:

   - IP Address: The three first numbers are the same as "IPv4 Address" on your computer, but the last number is different from the last on your computer and is between 1 ad 254 included.
   - Subnet Mask: same as your computer
   - Default Gateway (or "router"): The "IPv4" from your computer
   - DNS Server: same as your computer

Provided your computer is correctly configured for Internet sharing (including its firewall), this should be the configuration you need to access Internet with this network.